# unable to locate element //span[contains(text(), 'Ticket Created')]

Tags: python, selenium

When I run manually, `//span[contains(text(), 'Ticket Created')]` can be located.

but when I run phantomJS and Selenium;

```
WebDriverWait(driver, medium_timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, check)))
```

cannot locate this element.

Any idea?
Thanks in advance

Comment: can u get page source by `driver.page_source` which contains that xpath?

Comment: what do you mean. I use this xpath in console of Chrome, it works manually

Comment: `print driver.page_source` in python - is `medium_timeout` a variable like `medium_timeout = 100`

Answer (score 0):

I did driver,reflesh() to clear everything. reflesh triggers the issue.
Now it solved